# Triggering event when Button is pressed down in Android

Tags: android, button

I have the following code for Android which works fine to play a sound once a button is clicked:

```
Button SoundButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
        SoundButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(2);

    }
});
```

My problem is that I want the sound to play immediately upon pressing the button (touch down), not when it is released (touch up). Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe using a `OnTouchListener`? I guess MotionEvent will have some methods for registering a touch on the object.

```
   button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return false;
    }
   }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Got the following errors when trying to use that code:
- The type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)
- The method onTouch(View, MotionEvent) of type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must override a superclass 
  method
- MotionEvent cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: The answer is to change compiler level to 1.6 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 36):

You should do this:
b is the button.

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    mSoundManager.playSound(2);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still getting these errors:
- The type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent) 
- The method onTouch(View, MotionEvent) of type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must override a superclass method 
- MotionEvent cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: The code supplied in both of these answers appears to be correct. Add an import to `android.view.MotionEvent`. Here is the documentation for `OnTouchListener`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: Nice, got it to work after importing MotionEvent and using this line:
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

Comment: Thanks a lot sw333t! event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) works for me neither, your solution with event.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) works perfect!

Comment: Edited the answer with sw333t fix

Comment: Would anyone pls explain what the following checks for here: if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )

Comment: Worked perfectly for a onTouch + SoundPool

Answer (score 3):

`import android.view.MotionEvent;`