# Enable touch feedback for every buttons

Tags: android, button, touch-feedback

With `Android Studio` I have some `Buttons` and I want that when I click on them you can see a kind of movement that confirm you have clicked that `Button`. Is there a way to do that without create a new `xml` file in which there is a `selector`? 
I'd like to do something like that (I think it's default color):

[image] when is normal

[image] when is pressed

I have this but It doesn't do anything:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

[OnTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615690/569938) . You can capture key down and key up events to change the color.

You can try this :-

```
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: It doesn't work. In the same  `Button` I have this  `android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_share"`

Comment: In that scenario you have to use different drawable for this. Using the selector as you mentioned in the question.