# onOptionsitemSelected(MenuItem) of Type Appname(XXX) must override a superclass method

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, overriding

I am try'g to create an Simple application in Android. In one of my module I have to call the **options menu** that appears underneath the screen, when I click the **menu button** in the Android emulator.

Since I have to invoke a new activity, when one of my menu items in option menu is tapped, I put `@Override` before the method `onOptionsSelectedItem(MenuItem menuitem)` in order to implement my own definition instead of calling the parent activity.

Once I put the annotation `@Override` before `onOptionsSelectedItem(MenuItem menuitem)` method, its showing the following error...(in compile time itself)

The method `onOptionsitemSelected(MenuItem)` of type `SingleShooterRecordShots` (MyClass) must override a superclass method....

Comment: Is your class extending Activity?

Comment: This is the response for my own post , i changed the project properties java compiler compliance level from 1.5 t0 1.6,then that error got vanished....Thanks lot...

Comment: Thanks Falmarri for your response,,,Keep helping...

Answer (score 0):

This (more general) question has the same answer: ['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclipse)