# How to make a Grails Maven project use Java 1.7 in GGTS?

Tags: java, maven, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Grails 2.3.7 project which should use Java 1.7. 
I am using the Spring GGTS IDE as development tool and it is configured to use a Java 1.7 JDK.

I created the project in GGTS and changed the source and target level to 1.7. 
Then I generate a maven pom file with the create-pom command.
So far so good. The project is linked to use a JRE System Library of version 1.7.

Then I change the project to be a Maven project in GGTS. What happens now is that in GGTS, the project  changes the JRE System Library to become of version 1.6. I can manually switch it back to a java 1.7 library but every time I do a "Maven update project", the 1.6 library is back.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, give me a reason why you down-vote my question.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3539194/592139) may help - try configuring the source and target versions correctly in the POM.

Comment: P.S. I wasn't the downvoter...

Comment: maven-compiler-plugin is already configured to be 1.7 and when I build it by using maven, it uses java 1.7. It is only in GGTS that the project links to a java 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the jre 1.6 as installed jre from GGTS, the project will use my jre 1.7. But in the list of linked dependencies it is still labeled `JRE System Library [Java-SE 1.6]` even though it points to my 1.7 instance. This solved my build-issues even though it still looks wrong.