# Unable to compile simple Java 10 / Java 11 project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-10, java-11, module-info

I have a trivial Maven project:

```
src
└── main
    └── java
        └── module-info.java
pom.xml
```

pom.xml:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>example</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>10</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I build the project via `mvn -X install -DskipTests=true`, it fails:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project example: Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.parse(AsmModuleInfoParser.java:80)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.getModuleDescriptor(AsmModuleInfoParser.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager.resolvePaths(LocationManager.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.preparePaths(TestCompilerMojo.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:762)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:176)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov The bug has been resolved and one can now [make use of the `maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0` to fix the above error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/1746118).

Answer (score 266, accepted):

As of 30Jul, 2018 to fix the above issue, one can configure the java version used within maven to any up to JDK/11 and make use of the **[`maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/download.cgi)** to specify a release of either 9,10,11 *without any explicit dependencies*.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>  <!--or <release>10</release>-->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

***Note***:- The default value for source/target has been lifted from 1.5 to 1.6 with this version. -- [release notes.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12317225&version=12341563)

---

***Edit [30.12.2018]***

In fact, you can make use of the same version of `maven-compiler-plugin` while compiling the code against JDK/12 as well.

More details and a sample configuration in how to [Compile and execute a JDK preview feature with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232681/compile-a-jdk12-preview-feature-with-maven).

Comment: This only works out of the box when maven is executed with Java 11. If your platform Java version is e.g. Java 8 (and so maven is executed with Java 8), you need to define a toolchain https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Comment: Note that the associated property is `maven.compiler.release`: `<properties><maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release></properties>`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire - So, we can replace this code with the one you gave ? <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

Comment: @MasterJoe2 Yes you should be able to do that, given you are upgrading to Java-11.

Comment: To be clear: You must run maven with a Java version that is equal to or higher than the release target version and the source target version.

Answer (score 144):

### UPDATE

**The answer is now obsolete. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/706317).**

---

`maven-compiler-plugin` depends on the old version of ASM which does not support Java 10 (and Java 11) yet. However, it is possible to explicitly specify the right version of ASM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>10</release>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You can find the latest at https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.ow2.asm%20AND%20a:asm&core=gav

Answer (score 38):

It might not exactly be the same error, but I had a similar one.

**Check Maven Java Version**

Since Maven is also runnig with Java, check first with which version your Maven is running on:

```
mvn --version | grep -i java
```

It returns:

> Java version 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle
>   Corporation, runtime: C:\tools\jdk\openjdk1.8

**Incompatible version**

Here above my maven is running with `Java Version 1.8.0_151`.
So even if I specify maven to compile with `Java 11`:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

It will logically print out this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project efa-example-commons-task: Fatal error
>   compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

**How to set specific java version to Maven**

The logical thing to do is to set a higher Java Version to Maven (e.g. Java version 11 instead 1.8).

Maven make use of the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to find the Java Version to run. So change this variable to the JDK you want to compile against (e.g. OpenJDK 11).

**Sanity check**

Then run again `mvn --version` to make sure the configuration has been taken care of:

```
mvn --version | grep -i java
```

yields

> Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\tools\jdk\openjdk11

Which is much better and correct to compile code written with the Java 11 specifications.

Comment: This worked for me, also when using maven-assembly-plugin version 3.2.0

Answer (score 31):

Specify maven.compiler.source and target versions.

1) Maven version which supports jdk you use. In my case JDK 11 and maven 3.6.0.

2) pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

As an alternative, you can fully specify maven compiler plugin. See previous answers. It is shorter in my example :)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

3) rebuild the project to avoid compile errors in your IDE.

4) If it still does not work. In Intellij Idea I prefer using terminal instead of using terminal from OS. Then in Idea go to file -> settings -> build tools -> maven. I work with maven I downloaded from apache (by default Idea uses bundled maven). Restart Idea then and run `mvn clean install` again. Also make sure you have correct **Path**, **MAVEN_HOME**, **JAVA_HOME** environment variables.

I also saw this one-liner, but it does not work.

```
<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
```

I made some quick starter projects, which I re-use in other my projects, feel free to check:

- https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/mvn-pmd-java11
- https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/pmd-java-14

Answer (score 27):

Boosting your `maven-compiler-plugin` to `3.8.0` seems to be necessary but not sufficient. If you're still having problems, you should also make sure your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to Java 10 (or 11) if you're running from the command line. (The error message you get won't tell you this.) Or if you're running from an IDE, you need to make sure it is set to run maven with your current JDK.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using spring boot then add these tags in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    `<maven.compiler.release>`10</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

You can change java version to 11 or 13 as well in `<maven.compiler.release>` tag.

Just add below tags in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

You can change the 11 to 10, 13 as well to change java version. I am using java 13 which is latest. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to explicitly set **JAVA_HOME** to JDK-11 in my script though the terminal shows Java 11 version.

This was because, I'm executing `mvn` through shell script and `mvn` was using default JDK of my machine which was JDK8.

I confirmed which JDK version is being used by `mvn` in script & set to JDK-11 as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(java -version)
echo $(mvn --version | grep -i java )

export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk11/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

echo $(java -version)
echo $(mvn --version | grep -i java )
```

Answer (score 1):

`mvn` may be using `JAVA_HOME`, but if setting it doesn't work, there may be overrides in the actual mvn scripts

For example, on my system (mac), which mvn points to `/usr/local/bin/mvn`
which actually points to `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/bin/mvn`, which is a bash script pointing to `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec/bin/mvn` and that script reads like this at the top:

```bash
if [ -z "$MAVEN_SKIP_RC" ] ; then

  if [ -f /usr/local/etc/mavenrc ] ; then
    . /usr/local/etc/mavenrc
  fi

  if [ -f /etc/mavenrc ] ; then
    . /etc/mavenrc
  fi

  if [ -f "$HOME/.mavenrc" ] ; then
    . "$HOME/.mavenrc"
  fi

fi
```

So it shows it's looking in 3 different places for env, unless `MAVEN_SKIP_RC` is set.

If I run `MAVEN_SKIP_RC=1 mvn -version`, now the JAVA_HOME is taken into account.

but the real fix is to find the culprit in the mavenrc files

In my case, the only file present was `/etc/mavenrc` and it read:

```bash
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

So it was setting java 1.8 as the default, overriding the original JAVA_HOME.

change that to -v 11 and it works as expected.
Or simply remove the /etc/mavenrc altogether to restore the default to the JAVA_HOME value.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so for me nothing worked.
I was using spring boot **with** hibernate. The spring boot version was ~2.0.1 and I would keep get this error and null pointer exception upon compilation. The issue was with hibernate that needed a version bump. But after that I had some other issues that seemed like the annotation processor was not recognised so I decided to just bump spring from 2.0.1 to 2.1.7-release and everything worked as expected.

You still need to add the above plugin tough
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works and even after you set JAVA_HOME to a *correct* path, check if there is no override of the JAVA_HOME path in `<user>/.mavenrc`!

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

- "echo $JAVA_HOME" shows version 11
- "java -version" shows version 11
- However, "mvn -version" shows "Java version" is NOT 11

I paste this on the top of .bash_profile and source it. It works.

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME;export PATH=$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME;export PATH=$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'

java11
```