# Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm using the Redhat ubi8/8.3-227 image to execute maven tasks in Jenkins.

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.0
Java version: 17.0.4

java -version
openjdk version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19 LTS
```

For some reason I get the following error while compiling the code:

```
mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile: Fatal error compiling: error: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
  <source.version>${java.version}</source.version>
  
  <boat-maven-plugin.version>0.16.1</boat-maven-plugin.version>
  <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>3.3.0</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
  <docker-maven-plugin.version>0.40.2</docker-maven-plugin.version>
  <dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>1.4.13</dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>
  <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.8</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
  <jgitflow-maven-plugin.version>1.0-m5.1</jgitflow-maven-plugin.version>
  <flatten-maven-plugin.version>1.2.7</flatten-maven-plugin.version>
  <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
  <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
  <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
  <maven-deploy-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
  <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
  <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
  <maven-install-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-install-plugin.version>
  <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
  <maven-release-plugin.version>3.0.0-M6</maven-release-plugin.version>
  <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
  <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-shade-plugin.version>
  <maven-source-plugin.version>3.2.1</maven-source-plugin.version>
  <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
  <maven-site-plugin.version>4.0.0-M3</maven-site-plugin.version>
  <openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>5.4.0</openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>
  <spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>2.6.8</spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>
  <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.1.2184</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
  <versions-maven-plugin.version>2.11.0</versions-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I've already tried to enforce JAVA_HOME this way:

```
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el8_6.x86_64"])
```

But the result didn't change.

Here the output of mvn clean verify:

```
+ mvn -X -V clean verify -Dcheckstyle.skip=true 
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17.0.4, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.0.8-2.el8_6.x86_64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1160.81.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
.
.
.

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.854 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-26T15:12:11+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project async-support: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project async-support: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: error: release version 17 not supported
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1209)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: release version 17 not supported
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.reportDiag (Arguments.java:889)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.handleReleaseOptions (Arguments.java:311)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs (Arguments.java:350)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init (Arguments.java:246)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1209)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :async-support
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
```

I've recently updated the Java version, so the issue is most likely in the Maven/Java config rather than in the code.

Comment: Just use only `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` ......furthermore the output `mvn -version` looks a bit strange...because the hash is missing like `Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)`.... ?

Comment: maven compiler release didn't help. The output was truncated by me.

Comment: What does that mean? Same result? Please make add more details about the output error ... log... or also please post the full output of the jenkins like `mvn -V clean verify` ... the important part is the beginning of the build it should be up to [INFO] Scanning for projects...`....

Comment: The error output implies `error: release version 17 not supported` that the setup for the JDK version which should be used for the build is not that what it should be (JDK17..) I suppose there is a JDK version less than 17 in used...

Comment: Added the output of mvn clean verify.

Comment: Can you please post the pom file or at least the part where maven-compiler-plugin is configured ... btw. is this a single module build or a multi module build?

Comment: Included more details in the pom.xml. As I've recently updated the Java version, I'd rather focus on the Maven/Java config rather than than on the code.

Comment: Sorry but the properties definition does not help... the configuration of the plugins is more important...

Comment: Added the plugin config. There's no other reference to the plugin in the pom.xml or anywhere else in the repo.

Comment: Do you use a spring boot parent? Best would be having a working example.. or a full logout of the build which fails (mvn -X ...) ...

Comment: Added the output of mvn -X. I cannot include any more information as it would be project-specific. No parent is being used.

Comment: I suspect maven forks a new JVM for some reason and that JVM is not java 17.

Comment: @parax did you happen to run into this in centos? I'm experiencing the same issue. confirmed JAVA_HOME, /etc/mavenrc, $HOME/mavenrc all point to java 17. Even maven -X shows it's running against java 17, not using fork. I can't fathom what the hell is going on?

Comment: You should check if you installed the jre or jdk. I happened to install the jre which was missing javac (which defaulted to java 11 which was present in the path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bumped into the same problem. I found a solution only because of comments from @Obb users above, but I decided to put this answer if somebody needs it.

The problem was with java-17-openjdk from yum install. It installs not JDK but JRE. It doesn't have javac, so if you run maven build with JAVA_HOME that points to JRE it leads you to this type of error.

**Solution for me was** - *Install the full/correct JDK version and point JAVA_HOME to it.*

Comment: Spent a lot of time and then found this answer. Thanks a lot @InfoShym81. This really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same error in a different setting. So, just for the record: You might get the same error using Github actions for your CI/CD, if you didn't update the Java version in the .github yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same cause but this may help others. With Maven 3.9.3, the same error message is produced when minor version numbers are included e.g.

```
error: release version 20.0.1 not supported.
```

You might make this mistake if you have just exported the JAVA_HOME for maven ([another cause of this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468580/maven-invalid-target-release-10)).

I solved this by only including the major version number.

```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <java.version>20</java.version>
       <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
   </properties>
```

These are the only properties needed to specify the Java version. The major version can be checked with

```
javap -verbose target/classes/Foo.class | grep 'major version'
```

major version: 64