# Netbeans 9.0 with JavaFx 11 and JDK 11

Tags: javafx, gluon, java-11, netbeans-9, javafx-11

I am trying to run JavaFX 11 on NetBeans 9
Since JDK 11 does not have JavaFX anymore I couldn't get NetBeans to run a JavaFX project, it says: `"Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform."`

I then downloaded the javafx11 from this website https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/,
after following the tutorial I was able to compile and run a JavaFX class normally through terminal.
The only way I could add JavaFX is by using Maven, but I can't run the application  even that it was built successfully.

```
    Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
 Command execution failed.
```

Is there any other way to run JavaFX 11 with NetBeans? or maybe Eclipse?

Comment: It is separated into **OpenJFX** now, as it was already some time for Linux.

Comment: exactly but i cant run it in IDE

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk), already has a solution for NetBeans 9

Comment: i did try it but it also didn't work
as i said Running on terminal method worked with me.
Modular Project :always gives an error in module.
maven way: it build but doesn't run.

Comment: Then try to follow the steps provided in the answer, all of the different possibilities should be working for you too.

Comment: i think the problem is with exec-maven-plugin because netbeans error says:
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ last2 ---
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
but it works when i run it in terminal  using: mvn compile exec:java

Comment: the only way i could run the app is by editing the execute Goals in the Project Properties ->Actions to "exec:java" which is of course not the best way to do it

Comment: Looks like your using version `1.5.0` of the exec-maven-plugin. The latest version is `1.6.0`. Try using the latest version to see if that helps.

Comment: unfortunately i did try it with 1.6.0 but still no luck

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the main files of your project, a screenshot of the project structure, and something that allows us to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a late answer, but, it is possible to have javafx 11 maven project + NetBeans 9.

1. Maven doesn't like extending Application in a main clas. You should use two classes:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp.main(args);
    }
}
```

MainApp.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        String a;
        a = new String("test");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

2. Your pom.xml should look like this:

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

           <groupId>YOUR GROUP ID</groupId>
           <artifactId>YOUR ARTIFACT ID</artifactId>
           <version>YOUR VERSION</version>

           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                   <version>11</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
                   <version>11</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
                   <version>11</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                   <version>11</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>

           <build>

               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>3.8.0</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <source>11</source>
                           <target>11</target>

                           <fork>true</fork>
                           <executable>PATH TO javac binary i.e. /usr/local/java/jdk-11.0.1/bin/javac</executable>


                           <compilerArgs>
                               <arg>-verbose</arg>
                               <arg>-Xlint:unchecked</arg>
                           </compilerArgs>

                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                       <configuration>
                           <archive>
                               <manifest>
                                   <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                               </manifest>
                           </archive>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>1.2.1</version>
                       <executions>
                           <execution>
                               <goals>
                                   <goal>java</goal>
                               </goals>
                           </execution>
                       </executions>
                       <configuration>
                           <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>3.1.0</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <archive>
                               <manifest>
                                   <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                               </manifest>
                           </archive>
                           <descriptorRefs>
                               <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                           </descriptorRefs>
                       </configuration>
                       <executions>
                           <execution>
                               <id>make-assembly</id>
                               <phase>package</phase>
                               <goals>
                                   <goal>single</goal>
                               </goals>
                           </execution>
                       </executions>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </build>
           <name>YOUR ARTIFACT ID</name>
       </project>
   ```

This will work in netbeans without any issues.
Basically, what you need to do is start new maven project and after you finish setting project just replace pom.xml.

This way your code will run from IDE, and will compile correctly so that you can run it from command line with java --jar. Also, you will be able to run NB debugger.

Comment: An update for Netbeans 10 that helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCdBmPfzeyM

Comment: You are creating Maven project also. I don't see what is different?

Comment: The guy gives full answer including dependencies and nbactions.xml changes that I followed and work exactly as intended in Netbeans 10

Answer (score 1):

> This error is shown since the Java 11 launcher checks if the main class extends javafx.application.Application. If that is the case, it is required to have the javafx.graphics module on the module-path.

Stolen from [javafx documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)