# package x is declared in the unnamed module, but module x does not read it

Tags: java, javafx, java-module, java-platform-module-system, javafx-11

I want to migrate to Java 11 and JFX11 using netbeans.  JFX11 must be used as module, so I have added the JavaFX jars and added the following in my module-info.java under the default package folder.

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.swing;

requires java.logging;
requires java.desktop;
requires java.sql;
requires java.xml;
```

This causes all of my other dependencies to display the following errors when I try a clean and build in netbeans 9.

```
pacakges 'xyz' is not visible ... (package 'xyz' is declared in the unnamed 
    module, but module 'xyz' does not read it)
```

Can I not mix modules and libraries? What am I missing?

Comment: "JFX11 must be used as module", is not the case, you can use classpath as well. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk) for both cases

Comment: Adding the module path to the VM arguments worked. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Did you end up doing a module or just classpath?

Comment: I added the JavaFX jars as libraries which allowed the build to compile. Then I added "java --module-path PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls" to the VM arguments section in netbeans which let the build actually execute.

Comment: @nullpointer I don't think this is a duplicate question.   This question is, "Can I not mix modules and libraries?", with specific reference to the error message in the title (which is how I got here).  The other question that this is marked a duplicate of does not address that issue.

Comment: @swpalmer the linked question suggests exactly how a modular application needs the dependencies to be on the `modulepath` and not `classpath`.

Comment: @nullpointer Sure, but that doesn't solve the problem with this error message.  The error message itself is very confusing,  How can a module not read itself?  I encountered this in a different context and have yet to figure it out.  The module system is currently a big mess IMO. From what I can tell, the modules removed in JDK 11 cannot be added as modules to a new runtime using jlink because the replacement projects are not yet fully modularized.  I got this error trying to use a non-modular jar in my project on the classpath.

Comment: @swpalmer *How can a module not read itself?* .... `xyz` in the question is both the name of a ***package** which is not read by a **module*** at the same time. To what you're pointing out further is possibly using automatic modules with `jlink` which is true. But not sure about your exact use case without prior knowledge over it.

Comment: @nullpointer I guess the big mystery is where did module X come from, given that package X is in a non-modular Jar that is only on the classpath. It has no module-info or automatic module name in the manifest.  I guess you can't have a modular app that uses the unnamed module from the classpath, but this is a strange error message.

Comment: @swpalmer Agreed, the mystery would remain unless the question is clear enough and has further details. But there definitely must have been a module that's present on the modulepath is what I could infer certainly.