# Upgrading to Java 11 JavaFX headache

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-11

today I installed JDK 11 and all my JavaFX stuff went haywire. 
Fair enough, Oracle can do what they want. I'm trying to get my project back to a runnable state and this is the first time i've come across this modular stuff so no idea really what's going on.

I've managed to import the libraries as dependencies in Maven (although it couldn't find version 11 in maven of some of the libraries and I end up using 11-ea+19 for javafx-controls etc. - whatever..), so my code compiles fine with these dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11-ea+25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>11-ea+19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11-ea+19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Yeah I need them all.

So now I hope to run the program but no! We get an error at runtime:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Ok people have this problem all the time it seems, because they haven't added the "modules". The only problem is the people who are posting about this are not using maven and have downloaded a JavaFX SDK stored somewhere on their PC. Does Maven download these in a clever way or do I have to do the same thing and download a separate SDK? Then add the modules from there?! This looks a bit shoddy to me...

Really what I want to know is what I should put as my `--module-path` in order that I can `--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.swing`

Apologies for my frustrated tone. One of those days.

EDIT:
Here is my entire pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cricket</groupId>
    <artifactId>CricketFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+19</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for timezones -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.rxjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava-apache-http</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag/animated-gif-lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madgag</groupId>
            <artifactId>animated-gif-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jcodec/jcodec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcodec-javase</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>application.gui.AppStarter</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The exec-maven-plugin is not finding version 1.6.0, but I can clearly see it there in central repo on maven website. What the hell..same problem trying to get version 11 of the javafx libs.

EDIT: SOLVED: Something clearly wrong with my Maven setup, now using maven-exec-plugin version 1.4.0 and the thing works.

Comment: Check these answers about getting started with JavaFX 11: [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470141/3956070), [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144931/how-to-add-javafx-runtime-to-eclipse-on-java-11) or [NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk)

Comment: Have done all of this. Same problem.

Comment: Check your local maven version running `mvn -version`. See if you have a recent version?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: I have that version too, but I don't have any issues finding exec plugin 1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Please first remove all 11-ea+19 and put 11
I do not know why you can not find this version. See here for example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/11

Please add this plugin to maven pom.xml:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And after that execute:

```
mvn compile exec:java
```

This in eclipse is right button on the project -> Run As -> Maven build ...
and for the goals add:

```
compile exec:java
```

You also can see the example: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Hope I help. By the way this only will start you application in eclipse. I still do not know how to create executable jar and also jar which is backward compatible.

Happy coding!

Comment: Where in your pom you write which jdk you are using? I think you must have some compile properties that said java 11 - maven.compiler.source and target

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try it! It looks promising.