# How do I enable JavaFX on NetBeans 10 / JDK11

Tags: java, javafx

All my attempts to find out how to set up JavaFX on NetBeans have got bogged down with instructions for older versions that don't seem to work now. If I do file | new project | JavaFX Applicationm I get the message:

```
Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform. 
Please go to Platform Manager, create a non- 
default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, 
enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime. 
Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website.
```

But if I go to Platform Manager and create a non-default Java SE platform, there is no JavaFX tab.

Are there any up-to-date instructions anywhere?

Comment: Duplicated of [JavaFX deployment library not found in active JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk/51991162#51991162), and as stated in the answer below, there is a full tutorial on how to get [JavaFX 11+ with NetBeans 10](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this , This is an updating docs about using JavaFX with Netbeans with JDK 11 . You can also find how to integrate java with other IDE like IntelliJ and Eclipse : https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Thanks, that gets me partway. But when it says "Warning: Don't try to create a JavaFX project. The JavaFX ant tasks of the current Apache NetBeans version are not ready for JavaFX 11 yet. You can try to switch the Java project to a JavaFX project instead, from Properties -> Build -> Deployment -> Switch Project to JavaFX Deployment Model" I can't find any such option. And when although my FX code now compiles, build fails with "JavaFX deployment library not found in active JDK."

Comment: You should expand your answer by directly including those directions. The link has already been updated to JavaFX12 will likely continue to change with new releases.