# How to solve package is declared in module, but module does not read it?

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, java-module, modularization

I am migrating my development environment to another pc. I use NetBeans 10, open JDK11, JavaFX. When I import the main project into NetBeans I get the following error:

on:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

error is:

```
package java.util.logging is not visible
```

package `java.util.logging` is declared in module java.logging, but module javafx.swing does not read it.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk) help?

Comment: you have to say something simiar to the following in `module-info.java`. `opens sed.work.ez_proxy_gui_utility_2_maven.menu_options to javafx.fxml;
    exports sed.work.ez_proxy_gui_utility_2_maven.menu_options;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX deployment library not found in active JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk)

Comment: I don't have a module-info.java...In old development environment this i don't have this error, but the code is the same..