# How to fix 'Package is declared in module, but module does not read it' error in IntelliJ JavaFX?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've created a JavaFX project using **IntelliJ**, together with Maven. I'm trying to test some system that adds items into an XML file and then parses it and shows me all the items added to the file.

I want to use **FasterXML/Jackson** for parsing the files. In my `pom.xml`, I've added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

(...) and I also loaded the Maven changes from the button provided by IntellJ. I also pressed the **Reload all Maven Changes** button. The "Dependencies" folder seems to be all okay. I've received no errors or complaints:
[image]

However, when I'm trying to import some Jackson-related class, such as `ObjectMapper`, like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

(...) I receive such an error:
`Package 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind' is declared in module 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind', but module 'com.example.demo1' does not read it`.

This is my project structure:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to fix my problem. In my `module-info.java` I needed to add the following line of code:

```
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
```

Found something similar in an answer provided to a question on Stack ([How to solve package is declared in module, but module does not read it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567260/how-to-solve-package-is-declared-in-module-but-module-does-not-read-it)), although the user who answered said you need to also open the module.
Opening the module, though, would result in some other error, but just mentioning it as a requirement should be enough.

Comment: I have the same problem with javax.ws.rs but your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I can't add my dependency to my module-info because it's not itself modularized.

Comment: First, I wanted to thank you as your answer ended hours of frustration.  Is there something that we can do to avoid this in the future?  I used Inteli-J's Maven integration to add the dependency, I would have thought it would have made this change on its' own.  Is this a case of Inteli-J being so configurable, and dependent on extensions and add-ons to do things?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in IntelliJ

For anyone still dealing with this issue, I found that it was due to not exporting the controller to java.fx and java.base in the module-info.java

This is assuming that you're using MVC and have a controller package with all controller classes inside

This was the fix:

```
exports controller;
opens controller to javafx.fxml;
```

Also make sure that you add this for the model package in the same file (module-info.java):

```
opens model to javafx.base;
```