# The package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind is not accessible Java (268436910)

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, dependencies

I have recently explored handling JSON data with the org.json library and all went well.
Now I started a bigger Maven project, for which I intend to use the Jackson libraries in stead.
Sadly, it does not seem to work for me. I wanted to try out the ObjectMapper class, that VScode autocompleted for me, which also automatically adds the required import:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

However, I also immediately get an error on that line:
"**The type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is not accessible Java (16778666)**"

I have added the necessary dependencies to my pom.xml file like so:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Am I missing something? Are there any other steps that I should have taken?

Comment: when you go from command line to the folder where you have your pom.xml and exectue `mvn clean package` what it shows?

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project
 main: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/.../main/src/main/java/com/picit/DataHandler.java:[3,29] package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.picit does not read it)

Comment: I have to say I had assumed that maven comes automatically with JavaFX, as I could simply create a Maven project with VScode., but apparently it does not. I did not have maven installed apparently, as "mvn -v" initially was not recognized, so just now I download maven and added it to my classpath. I executed "mvn clean package" as shown above, but it did not help. I have the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only dependency needed for `ObjectMapper` is

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

This error occurs, because Jackson library is not included in your project's classpath. Probably your project is using the Java Platform Module System (JPMS); then log would also contain:

> ... declared in the "unnamed module" ... module does not read it.

If this is the case, add a `requires` directive to `module-info.java` file to specify that this module requires the jackson-databind library:

```
module correct.module.name {
  requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
}
```

After adding this `requires` directive recompile the project again.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. This step wasn't explained in the several tutorials that I read.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Maven problem. You probably have created a package-info.java for your project and so all your dependencies ended up on the module path but your package-info.java is missing the corresponding declarations.

You have to add a line like this:

```
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
```

See also: [How to fix 'Package is declared in module, but module does not read it' error in IntelliJ JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072026/how-to-fix-package-is-declared-in-module-but-module-does-not-read-it-error-in)