# NetBeans: "Failed to automatically set-up JavaFX Platform"

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I have been troubleshooting this error for the past few days - and have hit a brick wall. I am running NetBeans v11.3, and Ubuntu Bionic (v18.04.4).

I have installed Java versions 8 and 11 (openjdk) along with source code.

I have also installed javaFx versions 8 and 11 with source code.

I have even gone to "Tools -> Java Platform Manager" and ensured that v8 and v11 of Java are properly installed along with the appropriate  "Platform Sources".

But I still get the error mentioned when I try to create a new JavaFX project.

Any help would be very much appreciated.[NetBeans JavaFX project create error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f73aw.png)

Comment: Have you tried following the directions [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX deployment library not found in active JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to use JavaFX on openJDK, try out with Oracle JDK, as far as I know this is the best choice for using JavaFX, also try to edit the default platforms to match the appropiate system paths