# gitlab-CI doesn't build with maven and java 10?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci, java-10

It was working with java 8, but I changed to java 10 (I followed this post: [Unable to compile simple Java 10 project with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398894/unable-to-compile-simple-java-10-project-with-maven/51586202#51586202) )

I get this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-26T20:15:28Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project importparcoursup: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar compile
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nc.unc</groupId>
    <artifactId>importparcoursup</artifactId>
    <name>importparcoursup</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        // dependencies...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>10</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
              <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

complete project link: https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gitlab-ci.yml

Replace

```
image: maven:latest
```

with

```
image: maven:3-jdk-10
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you're using a JDK 8 or earlier to compile. This flag was introduced with Java 9. See `mvn -v` to verify.

Comment: The compilation works locally (I have java 10 installed). It's on gitlab.com that there is the error. I don't knows how to force gitlab to use java 10 instead of 8.