# Use java automatic module cdi.api with maven and java 9+

Tags: java, maven, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-info

I want to use CDI functionality in a java module. I'd like my code to remain generic and do not depend on a particular implementation.

I use Java 11 and Maven 3.6.0.

For a simplicity, my goal is reduced to importing package `javax.enterprise.context` in a java file. When I do so without module (without `module-info.java`) every thing works well.

Now when I add a `module-info.java` without requiring other modules, I get the following error message:

`package javax.enterprise.context is not visible (package javax.enterprise.context is declared in the unnamed module, but module javax.enterprise.context does not read it)`

Until now everything is OK. This message makes sens since I didn't require the CDI module.

To fix this I add `requires cdi.api;` to my `module-info.java`, only to get the following error:

`module not found: cdi.api`

My understanding is that the CDI library should take an automatic module name inspired by the jar file's name. When I run maven with `-X` directive I see `cdi-api-2.0.jar` in my classpath. I believe, correct if I'm wrong, this should translate to `cdi.api` automatic module name. But still this doesn't work.

Here is my minimal example:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>test.java.cdi</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
           <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

src/main/java/module-info.java:

```
module com.acme.test.cid {
    requires cdi.api;
}
```

src/main/java/com/acme/Main.java

```
package com.acme;

import javax.enterprise.context.*;

class Main {}
```

Any insights are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this using Maven (`mvn install`) or an IDE (IntelliJ maybe) ?

Comment: I use command line ("mvn clean install" more precisely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run maven with -X directive I see `cdi-api-2.0.jar` in my
>   classpath. I believe, correct if I'm wrong, this should translate to
>   `cdi.api` automatic module name. But still this doesn't work.

No, the modules resulting into the classpath are translated into [the unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module).

> module not found: cdi.api

Indicates that the `cdp.api` module was not found on the modulepath.

---

I tried reproducing the same, yet the same reproducible code worked fine for me, but notice my logs read :

> ```
> [DEBUG] Classpath:
> [DEBUG] Modulepath:
> [DEBUG]  .../Desktop/cdipi/target/classes
> [DEBUG]  .../.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/2.0/cdi-api-2.0.jar
> [DEBUG]  .../.m2/repository/javax/el/javax.el-api/3.0.0/javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar
> [DEBUG]  .../.m2/repository/javax/interceptor/javax.interceptor-api/1.2/javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
> [DEBUG]  .../.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
> [DEBUG] Source roots:
> [DEBUG]  .../Desktop/cdipi/src/main/java
> [DEBUG]  .../Desktop/cdipi/target/generated-sources/annotations
> ```

Just make sure the `maven-compiler-plugin` in use if `3.6.0` or above to support the modulepath added in Java9 and above. You can do it [as specified in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/1746118)

Comment: My output looks like

[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  ../java11cdi/target/classes
[DEBUG]  ../.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/2.0/cdi-api-2.0.jar
[DEBUG]  ../.m2/repository/javax/el/javax.el-api/3.0.0/javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar
[DEBUG]  ../.m2/repository/javax/interceptor/javax.interceptor-api/1.2/javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]  ../.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  ../java11cdi/src/main/java

No trace for Modulepath in my output.

Is that normal?

Comment: @AhmadShahwan Trying to reproduce with exactly the same `pom.xml`. The compiler plugin getting used by default on my machine is `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1` and it certainly doesn't support `<release>` configuration as I was specifying previously. That should fix it for you as well.