# maven takes Java 1.5 default even if JAVA_HOME is set to JDK11

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using JDK 11 and my application has around 20 projects. Now I want my maven to pick JAVA_HOME instead of changing all pom.xml with maven-compiler-plugin or by properties.
I have set JAVA_HOME to JDK 11
Output of **mvn -v**

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:28+0530)
Maven home: /home/krawler/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.4.11-0.el7_6.x86_64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

But when I run **mvn clean install** I get below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project mavenKwlCommonLibs: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

Comment: You must explicitly tell the compiler what Java version you want to compile for.  This makes your build robust.

Comment: Also you should use the latest version of Maven to get the latest bugfixes for Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the JDK you use and the Java version you compile for. You can very well compile for Java 8 with a JDK 11 (just one example).

You need to set

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

in your POM to the Java version you want to build for (see also https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

For Java 11, have also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/927493.

Comment: I am already able to do it by changing all pom.xml files of application this way, but I don't want to do it. I want my maven to pick JAVA_HOME set for both source and target or release as per maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0

Comment: That cannot be done. We have a company parent POM to manage these versions. Alternatively, you can specify them on the command line.

Comment: The Maven pom.xml is supposed to be self-contained. If it worked differently depending on environment variables, that would not work too well on other people's machines and you'd need to provide additional setup instructions.

Comment: If you want to use maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0, you have to specify that as well. From your error message, you are currently using 2.3.2.  (But even 3.8.0 defaults to Java language level 1.6 and you are supposed to specify a higher version in your build)

Comment: Maven has its quirks.  Tedious but pays off in the long run.