# supported java versions for quarkus running on hotspot

Tags: quarkus

I read the docs from quarkus and it is said that the following jdk versions are supported:

> JDK 8 or 11+ installed with JAVA_HOME configured appropriately

**Actually, I have JDK 12 installed.** Can I use the following?:

```
<maven.compiler.release>1.11</maven.compiler.release>
```

`maven.compiler.release` is the same as:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
```

**EDIT:**

Quarkus works with:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.12</maven.compiler.source
<maven.compiler.target>1.12</maven.compiler.target>
```

or

```
<-- Note: 12 instead of 1.12 -->
<maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: starting with Quarkus 2.x, the minimal requirement is JDK 11+. JDK 17 is supported too.
JDKs newer than 17 should work but are not actively tested.

====

On Linux and MacOS, you can use JDK 8 to 13.

On Windows, you can use JDK 8 to 12 as we are affected by a JDK bug: see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5359 .

You can compile to something specific to your version if you are only planning to use the said JVM.

As for why our examples are all using JDK 8: they are built to also support native images via GraalVM and until very recently GraalVM only supported JDK 8. GraalVM 19.3.0 just added support for JDK 11 as a preview (and we are working on it).

Comment: No, **quarkus cannot compile on JDK 12**. compile error: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project test Fatal error compiling: error: release version 1.12 not supported -> [Help 1] `. However, with `<maven.compiler.release>1.11</maven.compiler.release>` it works.

Comment: You need to use `12`, not `1.12`.

Comment: yes, was my fault. With `<maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>` it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quarkus with Java 12. There are plenty of ways to configure Maven to use that version, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/2504224) for example.

Comment: And can I use Java 13? Why the docs said that quarkus only work with JDK 8 or 11+. In all quarkus-examples, 1.8 is used. If using java 12, do I must compile the source to lower versions (e.g. `<maven.compiler.release>1.11</maven.compiler.release>` ? The maven `release`-tag replaces three flags: -source, -target and **-bootclasspath**. So I set the "-bootclasspath" in quarkus implicitly. Is this ok or should I better use `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`?

Comment: I think either way would work. Java 13 should also work

Comment: Quarkus only works with `<maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>`. It fails when using `<maven.compiler.release>1.11</maven.compiler.release>`. Error: `Fatal error compiling: error: release version 1.11 not supported -> [Help 1]
`.  So quarkus has problems with the `maven.compiler.release`-tag with implicitly sets the `-bootclasspath`.

Comment: Can you please open a github issue you exact steps to reproduce the problem along with an example project that exhibits the behavior you describe? Thanks