# What is the supported JDK version for json-path 2.4.0?

Tags: java, maven, jsonpath, java-15

What is the supported JDK version for json-path 2.4.0? I went through the homepage, https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath but I couldn't find the supported JDK version.

#### Why I'm looking for this information

I'm using JDK15 in my system and when I'm trying to use json-path 2.4.0, I'm getting the compilation error: The type java.lang.String can not be resolved.

[image]

However, when I change the compiler level to JDK8, the problem goes away.

[image]

**My pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.self.quickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>starter</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**The result of `mvn clean verify`:**

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.305 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-31T07:51:31+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/80M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project starter: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Please run a Maven build with `mvn clean verify` and show us the errors that occur. Error messages in the IDE are unreliable.

Comment: @JFabianMeier - Now, I've added the result of `mvn clean verify` in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the property `maven.compiler.release` to the Java version you want to target. Otherwise Maven will assume Java 5.

See also

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

You can pretty much copy/paste it from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/927493