# Java version - Maven - Classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

So I have my maven project configured to Java9

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.9</source>
                <target>1.9</target>
                <compilerVersion>1.9</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But if I check the project build path it still says JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5] in eclipse (instead of JavaSE-9), so it basically uses Java1.5 and gives me a lot of errors. If I manually correct that entry, everything is fine. But shouldn't Maven handle the complete classpath settings? The answer to this is probabbly quite simple, but I cant figure it out.

Thanks!

[image: wron java version from the right jdk]

**EDIT**
The fix was to remove compilerVersion and edit the source and target tags:

```
<configuration>
    <source>9</source>
    <target>9</target>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First which Eclipse Version do you use?

Comment: Oxygen! can this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Check PATH of MAVEN and JAVA**

```
mvn -v
```

In the output check if "Java version" is pointing to 1.9

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T13:28:13+05:30)
Maven home: /Maven/3.5.2
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-119-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Step 2: Check JDK 9 is configured in IDE (eclipse / sts)**

- Go to Preferences > Java > Installed JREs :: [Check if Java 9 is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R73D.png)
- If Java 9 is not available, then Click **Add**
- Choose JRE Type **Standard VM / JVM** and click **Next**
- **JRE Home** -- Java 9 Home path.
- **JRE name** will get auto-filled and **JRE system libraries** will show **jrt-fs.jar** was loaded.
- Hit **Finish**
- Now you should see JVM 8 and 9 both [showing up in the Installed JREs section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC66p.png)
- Hit **Apply and Close**

**Step 3: Update your Maven Project for Changes to Take affect**

- Follow the tip given by [Justin Albano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2403253/justin-albano) and you are ready to work with your Maven Project using Java 9.

Comment: I am using the eclipse built-in maven. But it always sets down the version to SE1.5. If I set it to SE9 manually, some functions like call hierarchies and stuff like that wont work anymore, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Maven source version (`1.9` is your particular case) and the Eclipse source version fall out of sync, especially if the source version in the `pom.xml` file is changed *after* the project has been created in Eclipse. To bring the two back into sync, perform the following:

1. Right click on the project
2. Mouseover `Maven`
3. Click `Update Project...`

You can also update the Maven configuration using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. For more information, see [What causes imported Maven project in Eclipse to use Java 1.5 instead of Java 1.6 by default and how can I ensure it doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539139/what-causes-imported-maven-project-in-eclipse-to-use-java-1-5-instead-of-java-1).

Comment: I of course tried that, but sometimes eclipse seems to do stuff and then its SE1.5 again. I have to manually overwrite the classpath over and over again. Funny thing is, if I set it to JDK9, the entry in the classpath overview from eclipse disappears and everyhing is fine :(

Comment: So I tried a few things at it turned out, that the update projects resets the project to se1.5. The error needs to be somewhere else :(