# Android : Should I remove @Override from facebook.java?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook to my Android application. When i added internet permission in the project and have generated App_ID but when I put facebook files in to my project it gives these errors as shown in pic.

Now should I remove @Override or am I missing something.

If I put this code into my **OnCreate** method it also gives errors to remove @Override.

```
 facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
```

[image]

Should I include facebook.apk if yes then Where to add this? please help

I followed many tutorials but could not resolve these errors.

Comment: Have you checked java compiler version? Project properties>java Compiler, set it to 1.6. Generally this error comes due to it. If apk is generated after removing @Override then the application works fine in the projects i have seen. I hope this minor things helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you are switching between Java 1.5 and Java 1.6. In 1.5 you couldn't mark interface implementations with @Override, but you can in 1.6.

[@Override annotation error (android prefs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761888/override-annotation-error-android-prefs)

[Bug with Override annotations in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735661/bug-with-override-annotations-in-eclipse)