# ActionBarSherlock has a lot of errors

Tags: java, android, javac

This is my first time using an external library, and I'm a bit nervous about removing all of the errors. The library when added gives me the a whole bunch of errors with the same fix "Remove @Override annotation".

The fix for this is to increase my JDK to 1.6: [ActionBarSherlock library is full of errors after being imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165700/actionbarsherlock-library-is-full-of-errors-after-being-imported)

But now I'm worried about my other apps... Did I compile them the wrong way? Also, I have a JDK of 1.7 available, should I use that instead of 1.6? Sorry, I really don't know the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this very common issue as...

This is most likely because you are switching between Java 1.5 and Java 1.6. In 1.5 you couldn't mark interface implementations with @Override, but you can in 1.6.

[@Override annotation error (android prefs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761888/override-annotation-error-android-prefs)

[Bug with Override annotations in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735661/bug-with-override-annotations-in-eclipse)

['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips)

[Why do I get "must override a superclass method" with @Override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697513/why-do-i-get-must-override-a-superclass-method-with-override)

Also, I have a JDK of 1.7 available, should I use that instead of 1.6?

[Java 7 language features with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android)

[Does Android plan to support Java7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535164/does-android-plan-to-support-java7)

[How does Android's Java version relate to a Java SE version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version)

Comment: Yeah it works with 1.6, but I just want to know if my application will be more up to standard if it was in 1.7?

Comment: setting higher version will give you chance to use new feature introduced in java 7 but take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535164/does-android-plan-to-support-java7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version