# Getting errors while following facebook's mobile app guide

Tags: facebook, mobile

When I type this into my class:

```
package com.greatap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
FacebookError cannot be resolved to a type,
Syntax error on token "*", delete this token,
The import com.facebook.android.Facebook cannot be resolved,
The method onCancel() of type new DialogListener(){} must override a superclass method,
The method onComplete(Bundle) of type new DialogListener(){} must override a superclass method,
Facebook cannot be resolved to a type,
DialogListener cannot be resolved to a type,
DialogError cannot be resolved to a type.
```

If anyone could please help me find out what I did wrong, I would appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

change project preference to use Java 1.6 instead of 1.5. This error is because of using Java 1.5.

link: ['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclipse)