# Errors with Runing Android Source Code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to use the following code

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

I selected Create Project.Use the current source. Pointed it to the directory and click on Run. Following are the errors I am getting. [image: Error Images]Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and building again. If not, it's likely that Eclipse is not recognizing your Android SDK install location. Check it under your Android preferences.

Comment: Tried. I believe, I need to go for a clean installation since i am getting some weird errors too.

Answer (score 0):

check this out ['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclipse)

i would be willing to bet its the same issue, you can post some code but i dont think the @Override is there for the methods indicated in the error picture

Comment: Tried it but not working. I am adding the Files. Can you look if it is still appearing for you. If you can compile them and post an .apk version, I would be thankful. I think I need to clean up my all computer and might get rid of this error. I have uploaded the files here
http://uploading.com/files/7951d28b/App.rar/