# Why do I get "must override a superclass method" with @Override?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

The following code generates this error message at the `public void onClick` line.

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick
>     - The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

I can't understand why. This code is taken from numerous examples I've seen. What can possibly be wrong?

```
private Button audioButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    audioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    audioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View button) {
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                button.setSelected(false);
            }
            else {
                button.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips

Comment: If changing compiler to 1.6 don't work then refresh the project and build it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Check the project's properties and verify that **Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level** is set to **1.6** (or a later version).

It worked for me... i am using eclipse 2021.... and ..

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. This is so arcane. How is a newbie supposed to know this kind of thing??

Comment: However, now the program crashes with a forced close -- "has stopped unexpectedly". Wow, that's helpful.

Comment: I commented out the setOnClickListener statement, but left the findViewById line alone, and it still crashes! How can the mere act of obtaining the Button object cause the program to stop unexpectedly??

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the fact that it just doesn't like image buttons. If I use a normal button, it's okay. This is puzzling

Comment: I understand now: an ImageButton is not compatible with Button. *sigh*.

Comment: And I required an Eclipse restart

Comment: See my Answer (below) for an explanation of why this is necessary.

Comment: *"How is a newbie supposed to know this kind of thing??"* - A newbie is supposed to know how to Google ... and find this Q&A :-)  But seriously, there is no practical solution to the problem of computer programming being arcane.

Comment: Because I started my journey with Java 8, I am not sure, but is this something which wasn't there during Java 6?

Comment: This was there in Java 6.

Answer (score 58):

This is most likely due to a source code level incompatibility between Java 1.5 and 1.6.

- In Java 5, the `@Override` annotation requires that the method is actually overriding a method in a superclass.
- In Java 6 and later, the `@Override` annotation will *also* be satisfied if the method is implementing an abstract method in a superclass or interface.

So the most likely reason for seeing this in code that you expect to work is that you are compiling Java 6 (or later) code with a Java 5 compiler (or some other compiler with the compiler's source compliance level set to 5).

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining *why* the compiler compliance level is important.

Answer (score 7):

**MAVEN USERS**
If you're using Maven for build it can override the eclipse settings during build. So if you set Eclipse to 1.7 but don't specifically set the Maven JDK build version(which at the time of this writing defaults to 1.5), then it will reset eclipse target compiler back to 1.5. Set the Maven compiler as follows.

```
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>            
    </build>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the compiler to 1.6 and still get this error, try to check your imports, because what Eclipse does is that it always try to do this

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

instead of ->

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
```

That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's 2018! For easy reference, see screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's 2020 -

Project>Right Click>Java Compiler>Compiler Compliance Level> Change this to 1.8 [or latest level]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `View.onCLickListener()` solved the problem to me. My Java Compiler --> Compiler Compliance level is already set to 1.6 but still I was having the same problem.

But changing the code

```
rdBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onRadioButtonClicked(v);
            }
        });
```

to

```
rdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onRadioButtonClicked(v);
            }
        });
```

solved the problem in my case.

Comment: In short, your code imported the wrong `OnClickListener` class.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened because the Method I wanted to override was **package private** and I tried to override it from a different package.

Eclipse will additionally put a warning in that case that I didn't notice because of a ton of other warnings

Answer (score 0):

Now it's 2020! And you should change the compliance to 1.8 !

I tried changing the compliance to 1.6 but it didn't work. And I was trying randomly changing it to other levels like 11, 12 or 13 but it didn't work either.

After reading a bit I found this topic which has helped me to understand:
[What is “compiler compliance level” in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse)

Reading that the Java compiler can compile code that will run on prior versions of the JVM. I have changed the compiler level to **1.8** and it did solve the problem. So, always aim to the highest compliance level!

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your jdk version to minimum 1.8 in library section of buildpath.
2. Change your your project facets java version to 1.8 apply and close

Finally your issues will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

for someone using **vscode** with maven, you can add [these](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) settings to your pom.xml to let vscode use the preferred compiler version:

```xml
<project>
...
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
...
</project>
```