# android developer training errors in sample code for network connection

Tags: android

I am going through the android developer training material here - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html.  I downloaded the sample code NetworkUsage.zip and imported it to eclipse.  The code has error in SettingsActivity.java when I open it, "The method onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences, String) of type SettingsActivity must override a superclass method".

As far as I can see it is correctly defining the method and implementing the interface,  why is there an error?  From the android api I can see that this interface still exists and has not be deprecated or anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure but may it help

['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips)

Eclipse is defaulting to Java 1.5 and you have classes implementing interface methods (which in Java 1.6 can be annotated with @Override, but in Java 1.5 can only be applied to methods overriding a superclass method).

Go to your project/ide preferences and set the java compiler level to 1.6 and also make sure you select JRE 1.6 to execute your program from eclipse.

[Why do I get "must override a superclass method" with @Override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697513/why-do-i-get-must-override-a-superclass-method-with-override)