# Method...Must Override a Superclass Method (Latest SDK)

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “must override a superclass method” with @Override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697513/why-do-i-get-must-override-a-superclass-method-with-override)

I recently installed the latest Android SDK in a new eclipse set up on a new machine.  When I brought over an old project in several places I got a syntax error concerning @Override stating "method suchandsuch of type suchandsuch must override a superclass method".  These items were fixed by removing @Override (which I don't think is correct).

I just made my first new project with my new setup and the initial untouched code is giving this error which has me confused.

```
package com.geeksonhugs.whenimclose;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements ItemListFragment.Callbacks {

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
            ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
                    .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler accepts @Override before onCreate but gives the error with onItemSelected.  Can someone please clarify what is going on for me please?  Again this syntax error does not occur in prior versions?

Comment: Are the java versions the same?  I've seen something similar moving from Java 5 to Java 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are using `java compiler 1.5`, make it `1.6`,because `@Override of interface's methods is introduced after 1.5.`

In Eclipse,

> **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Compiler Compliance Level -> select
>   1.6**

Comment: but the OP says the compiler is accepting the `@Override` annotation for the onCreate method.

Comment: Ovveride annotation for interface's method is available since java 1.6

Comment: It was at 1.7?  Also I installed JDK 7 instead of JDK 6 if that's an issue?

Comment: Dont use 1.7 its not compitable,so just change it in 1.6

Comment: I set it to 1.6 but still it does not work.  On the preferences screen it says to "make sure I have a 1.6 compliant JRE installed".  Is my  1.7 backwards compatible with 1.6?

Comment: no need to install ,even i used 1.7 and set compiler level 1.6 it works perfectly.

Comment: I've done so and it's still not working :( ... could you please review my settings and note the warning it gives.  The second picture includes clicking the "configure" link from the first one. http://imagebin.org/219218
http://imagebin.org/219219

Comment: I cleaned it.  And not just superficially, I really got in there and got the gunk out...but still no joy.  I restarted eclipse.  Cleaned.  Rebuilt.  :(

Comment: i think you should install java1.6

Comment: In closing...installing Java 6 didn't help.  It turns out "PROJECT SPECIFIC" compiler settings were set for 1.5.  Damn! :-(  Anyway, on to the next obstacle! :-)

Comment: Anthony's last comment was key - it was the Project Specific settings that finally fixed the problem for me. It's not exactly intuitive.