# How to use String.format in java 8?

Tags: java, string, java-8

Today I wrote a simple program in eclipse Kepler in java 8. Actually, I copied it from some video tutorial. In that tutorial, it ran, but in my computer it didn't. Error line is

```
 String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);
```

I don't understand what the error is here.
It highlights the method `format(String,object[])` in the type `String` are not applicable for the `argument(String, int, int, int)`

```
public class Demo {

private int hour;
    private int second;
    private int minute;

    public void setTime(int h,int m,int s){
        hour=((h>=0 && h<24)?h:0);
        minute=((m>=0 && m<60)?m:0);
        second=((s>=0 && s<60)?s:0);
    }

    public String railwayTime(){
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);//error in this line
    }

    public String regular(){
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d %s",((hour==0 ||hour==24)?12:(hour%12)), minute, second, (hour>=12)?"AM":"PM");//error in this line
    }
}

public class ShowTime {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo d=new Demo();
        System.out.println(d.railwayTime());
        System.out.println(d.regular());
    }
}
```

Comment: As the exception states, you have to provide the formatting arguments as an array, not as individual arguments.

Comment: Using Java 8 here. I can't reproduce this error. Do you think you could show us some more code? And are you sure you're using Java 8 too?

Comment: `String.format` is introduced in Java 5 and since then it accepts `Object...`, I just don't understand how did ypu misused the standard library to get this result.

Comment: Read this: [What is "compiler compliance level" in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22584427), set your level to java 8 and then be happy.

Answer (score 6):

The exception asks you for an array instead comma-sepparated strings:

```
// incorrect
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);

// fast but correct
Object[] data = { hour, minute, second };
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", data);
```

But actually, method `format(String,object[])` does not exists in `String`, it is: `format(String pattern, Object... arguments)` what should work with commas `,`. There is something with your syntax, but not in the shown code.

Comment: `String data` -> `String[] data`

Comment: Also, surely `hour`, `minute` and `second` are `int`s, so this wouldn't compile. You should create `data` as `Object[] data = ...`

Comment: @rajeevranjan What was the previous setting for compliance level, such that it gave the error you saw?

Comment: @StuartMarks Most likely Java 1.4. In some IDE this is the standard level if you don't define something else.

Comment: @Tom Yes it must be 1.4 if varargs wasn't supported. But could the default for Eclipse Kepler (released 2013) really be 1.4 (released 2002)?

Comment: @StuartMarks Sadly it is. I'm not 100% sure if this is a problem with Eclipse itself or the installed JDK, but I experienced that myself during my time with Eclipse. I'm using IntelliJ and it currently uses Java 6 as the default (with JDK 8 installed). Kind of sucks :D.

Answer (score 1):

A real answer to this problem is only your type int.
You don't have to use Object specifically but you have to use a type that inherit from Object and int is a raw type that does not inherit from Object, like all raw types.
So you can use Integer instead of int to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have a guess.

```
private int hour;
private int second;
private int minute;
```

As above, you declared `hour`, `second` and `minute` as of int type which is a primitive data type and is not compatible to the `Object` type.

You might wanna change them to:

```
private Integer hour;
private Integer second;
private Integer minute;
```

`Integer` is a wrapper for the primitive type `int` and is used to objectify it.
By then, the line `String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);` should work fine.