# How to generate 4 digit random numbers in java from 0000 to 9999

Tags: java

I tried the following

```
int number = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 9999 + 1);
```

But it won't generate 4 digit numbers like 0004,0035 and so on...

I searched for similar questions but none solved, they were different from what I need, if there's already an existing question please let me know.

I need no genarate numbers like 1485 and 0180, not only numbers starting with 0.

Comment: An `int`  can not have leading zero's

Comment: What's the difference between 0004 and 4 as a number? You probably want to have strings.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar thanks I will delete.

Comment: Do you want integers, or strings? (What @Henry said)

Comment: @mbomb007 I need strings

Comment: `1000` is bigger than `1` and you specify the range as 1000-9999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
    Random r = new Random();
    String randomNumber = String.format("%04d", r.nextInt(1001));
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
```

**EDIT1**

```
    Random r = new Random();
    String randomNumber = String.format("%04d", Integer.valueOf(r.nextInt(1001)));
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
```

**EDIT2**

```
    Random r = new Random();
    String randomNumber = String.format("%04d", (Object) Integer.valueOf(r.nextInt(1001)));
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
```

All three versions should work.

Comment: The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String, int)

Comment: @hjx Updated. Use boxed Integer. Besides, both versions work for me.

Comment: unfortunately It didn't work too, are you importing something ?

Comment: the problem is with my ide, I tried in an online ide and it worked.

Comment: What Java version is it picking up ?

Comment: 1.8.0 java.........

Comment: Check this question for explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440073/how-to-use-string-format-in-java-8

Comment: It's not generating numbers like 1485, I expected it to generate both 0001 and 1000

Comment: `1485` is out of the range `[0000 to 1000]`. You may want to update your question with desired range.

Comment: String randomNumber = String.format("%04d", Integer.valueOf(r.nextInt(9999))); would work ?

Comment: it worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The integer values you generate will be correct for what you need. If you want to always have four characters, you can simply write the value to a String with leading zeros, like so;

```
String.format("%04d", number);
```

Comment: my ide says that number must be of type Object.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Auto boxing is available since quite some time now.

Comment: @henry eclipse..  
the problem is with my ide, I tried in an online ide and it worked.