# eclipse error, "Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new for eclipse, and could not find the solution for

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7.

I changed the Java Compiler from 1.6 to 1.8, but I still have this error.
The code is as below:

```
package learning;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert a command:");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        switch (text) {
            case "start":
                System.out.println("Game Started");
            case "stop":
                System.out.println("Game Stopped");
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

I just downloaded the latest eclipse and Java SED kit 8 yesterday. Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"I changed the Java Compiler from 1.6 to 1.8"* You mean you changed the Compiler Compliance Level? See this: [What is "compiler compliance level" in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22584427)

Comment: Yes.  Project -->Properties --> Java Compiler, then select Enable projects specific settings and select Compiler Compliance Level 1.8. And under the Java Build Path libraries, there is JRE1.8.0-45.

Comment: JRE? Try to select your JDK instead.

Answer (score 1):

Go in project properties->Java Compiler ... Change compliance level to 1.8

Comment: check in your project's build path libraries (can be navigated through project properties), if you are using correct jre/jdk version.

Comment: Under the libraries, there is JRE System Library (jre1.8.0-45). Is that correct?

Answer (score -2):

I have java 1.8, the following steps worked for me.

1) in eclipse.ini Change  java version = 1.7 and launch eclipse, change java compiler settings as 1.7

2) right click on the error, click change compilation settings.

Comment: This is not really a solution