# String value in Java 1.7 switch statement throwing an error?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7

Any one knows what is this error saying:

> An error occurred at line: 388 in the jsp file: /historical_weather.jsp
>
> Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

I am using `Java 7.0`. Still I get this error.
Thanks

Comment: You might have Java 7 installed but is that the library the project is using?

Comment: Yes Matthew, the project is using the same jdk 1.7

Comment: You may be using Java 7 but you are also using `-source 1.6` or lower.

Comment: Are you using the jspc [Maven plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin.html)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014654/eclipse-error-cannot-switch-on-a-value-of-type-string-for-source-level-below-1?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be happning because you are using Tomcat-7 or below.

Tomcat-7 uses source level as 1.6 to compile JSPs [Ref](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html). To resolve this problem you can to use Tomcat-8 since Tomcat-8 uses source level as 1.7 for JSPs.

Another solution, if you want to use Tomcat-7,  is to change source level as 1.7 in Tomcat-7, for that you have to add below entries for the servlet `jsp` in [TOMCAT_HOME]/conf/web.xml :

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.7</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.7</param-value>
</init-param>
```

For more detail : [how-to-set-tomcat-7-source-level-to.html](http://censore.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-set-tomcat-7-source-level-to.html)

Note: I am talking about only JSPs for whom Tomcat generates java code and compile them. For other Java classes source level would be same as your JDK version.

Comment: I am using java 7 and I set the compiler level was already set to 1.7. Though I had this issue. But this is the case in my problem. After I have changed my tomcat configuration, it worked. Thanks. Note: As per the link in the answer, we have to modify this jsp servlet: <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> only in tomcats web.xml .

Answer (score 2):

Check you project properties (regardless of the JDK installed you can always set a lower compiling level on every IDE) or your Maven build configuration.