# Javac symbol not found

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

This is for an intro course to Java, we are just learning about svn and what not. When I wrote and executed the program on eclipse it ran fine, I wanted to double check on command prompt after committing it to svn, but it returned the below error instead.

```
javac -d bin/ src/a0/Cfiltering.java src/driver/CfilteringDriver.java 

src/a0/Cfiltering.java:267: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method compare(int,int)
location: class java.lang.Integer
        return Integer.compare(ints[0] * 10 + ints[1],
                  ^
src/a0/Cfiltering.java:333: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method compare(int,int)
location: class java.lang.Integer
        return Integer.compare(ints[0] * 10 + ints[1],
                  ^
2 errors
```

I have no idea why this happens, the original code that caused the error is here:

```
Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<int[]>() {
  public int compare(int[] ints, int[] otherInts) {
    return Integer.compare(ints[0] * 10 + ints[1],
        otherInts[0] * 10 + otherInts[1]);
  }
});
```

Here are my imports:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Integer;
```

Comment: Looks like you're not using Java 7 (or Java 8).

Comment: Both school and my machine are on Java7, however mine is on "1.7.0_80" and school is on "1.7.0_79". Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: And you're using the correct [compliance level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse)?

Comment: I only have java7 installed on my machine

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to figure out what compliance means, everything is set to 1.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112727/discussion-between-gptt916-and-tom).

Comment: Have you already tried to compile the code using the console?

Comment: So, your problem is eclipse itself. Check the selected JDK, re-check the compliance level, try to clean and rebuild the project, try to re-import the project.