# Eclipse, Easily remove/fix all @Override due to Java version change

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am aware of ['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips) (my issue is the opposite, I need to remove the `@Override`s) and I understand the reason the error occurs.

**My question**

Is there an easy way to remove all of those errors, or remove all the errors of the same kind in one swoop? Kind of like solving all imports...

Thanks for any tips to help save time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

If you imported a Java 6 project and have Eclipse complaining about **@Override annotations** because you are compiling with Java 5...

- Make sure you have a file from the project open and selected in your workspace
- CTRL+H
- Change the Tab at the top from **Java Search** to **File Search**
- In **Containing Text** enter `@Override`
- In **File name patterns** enter `*`
- Select **Enclosing Projects** for your **Scope**
- Press **Search** to do a dry run to see what happens and what it finds

Then, if all looks good, proceed with:

- CTRL+H
- Change the Tab at the top from **Java Search** to **File Search**
- All your values should be remembered, if not follow the steps above from the dry run
- Press **Replace**

Example **Replace**

> Replacing 92 matches in 18 files

- **Replace:** field should have carried over `@Override`
- Remove anything/everything from the **With:** field
- Press **OK**

Awesome...no laborious removing of @Overrides ever again.

**Please NOTE**: Occasionally, for me at least, when pressing CTRL+H the **File Search** wont allow me to choose **Enclosing Projects** as a **Scope** or it will automatically search the entire Workspace as opposed to the project. This is resolved by ensuring a file from your project is open and focused in Eclipse.

Hope this helps others. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I do not know better way than find and replace all @Override by empty string. Eclipse can do it globally: press Cnrtl/H, write text @Override and leave the target empty. Then press "replace all" and pray... :(

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Pressing CTRL+H brings up many options. And when you say Global, that means all files in the project? All projects, or just that file? Thanks

Comment: Or you can use Search -> File and use the Replace button at the bottom. It's too bad you are not going the other way, Source -> Cleanup is the way to go, but they don't have an option to suppress the overrides.

Comment: @AlexR ?? Any further info? Please

Comment: Ctrl+H, then choose "File Search" tab. Unless you specify working set the search is performed for all projects in workspace.

Answer (score 4):

After removing all instances of "@Override", you can also add back the non-interface overrides using "Clean Up".

Steps (search/replace, then add back):

1. Select the projects or folders containing your source files.
2. Go to "Search > Search..." (Ctrl-H) to bring up the Search dialog.
3. Go to the "File Search" tab.
4. Enter "@Override" in "Containing text" and "*.java" in "File name patterns". Click "Replace...", then "OK", to remove all instances of "@Override".
5. Go to "Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Clean Up" and create a new profile.
6. Edit the profile, and uncheck everything except "Missing Code > Add missing Annotations > @Override". Make sure "Implementations of interface methods" is unchecked.
7. Select the projects or folders containing your source files.
8. Select "Source > Clean Up..." (Alt+Shift+s, then u), then "Finish" to add back the non-interface overrides.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Compiler compliance level ----> choose 1.6.
JAVA JRE 1.5 override is only superclass