# Facebook for Phonegap Java error - missing superclass

Tags: java, android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Im using PhoneGap version 2.1 and tried to incorporate the facebook-phonegap plugin ( https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect )

I followed the step by step tutorial but i ended up with this 3 errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ0gM.png

Any ideas how i can fix them ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the way to solve tis is either upgrade to higher JDK version or remove the @Override annotations :)
Simple but frustrating if you don't do every-Java dev