# How to commit preferences in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control, preferences

I have a couple of Error/Warning preferences (Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings) in Eclipse which are saved to .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs in my workspace. This file contains other settings specific to my local machine (e. g. the path to the JDK) so I don't want to store it in the version control repository and even if I did I would want it to be outside .metadata.

As of now, every new member of the team has to merge the preferences to their workspace manually which is cumbersome and error prone, not to mention the pain of distributing any changes across the team. Project specific settings *are* committed but what about worspace specific settings? Is it possible to store these preferences along with the code and make it apply itself to the workspace upon loading?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may resemble this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927484/is-settings-org-eclipse-jdt-core-prefs-part-of-the-project).
`org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` tells the JVM or IDE how you compile your project,so it is a part of the project and should be in the version control.
In fact you can find a file with the same name under your specific project's `.settings` folder,and configuration defined in workspace setiing is override in the specific project.
So store things belong to workspace in folder `.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\` and things belong to project in the project's `.setting` folder.