# Should I version control org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs on eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, svn

So 
I have eclipse project and want to make reproducable builds. From 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927484/is-settings-org-eclipse-jdt-core-prefs-part-of-the-project) topic I understand that the **core** folder

> .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

must be part of the SVN control.
But what about ui.prefs ? What does this folder contains?

In Spring-Boot I have seen configurations like:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</name>
                            <location>${main.basedir}/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</name>
                            <location>${main.basedir}/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</location>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Why is this folder so important?

Comment: Honestly: I would not rely on any IDE for repeatable builds. The build should run in maven (you obviously use it) and require only maven and maven-available plugins to complete. Just think about how much you lock yourself into the specific eclipse way to handle configuration. If this changes, you will be locked with the old platform until you can fix your build process.

Comment: It's not important for repeatable builds. What's said there does not( * ) apply to maven projects since all build relevant information is contained within pom files. It's targeted at plain eclipse projects. ( * some exceptions like setting system properties from within eclipse etc). What you see in your example is a way to setup repeatable eclipse workspaces (maven projects don't include any eclipse project.properties or so in vc). With settings like the right java formatter.