# Overriding a method with generic Map parameter

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have following code:

```
class Key{
 --Some Implementation
}

class A{
   public void grpMap(ConcurrentMap<Key,List<Key> keyList){ 
   --Some Implementation   
   }

}

public class B extends A{
   --Edited
   @Override -- [Made "O" capital case after kocko's reply]
   public void grpMap(ConcurrentMap<Key,List<Key> keyList){ 
   --Some Implementation   
   }


}
```

With above code i get following error in class B

> The method grpMap(ConcurrentMap) of type B must override
>   or implement a supertype method

My problem is i can't change the way `classes key, B and C` are declared as these are legacy classes.

Any suggestion on how to get rid of this error?

EDIT---

JDK version used is 1.6.43
I am using eclipse which will auto generate annotations.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips

Comment: Issue is not due to jdk version. I am using jdk 1.6

Comment: Show your stackTrace here..

Comment: Its a compile time error there is no stacktrace. Error is pasted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The annotation

```
@override
```

should be

```
@Override
 ↑
```

Also, check you Java version in the IDE - it should be 1.6, or newer, in order to get rid of the error.

Open `Project properties` -> `Java compiler` -> Set compliance level to `1.6` -> OK.

Comment: That was a typo. COrrected it. I am using eclipse, so it generates annotations on its own.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Jdk 1.6. Also i believe jdk version 1.5 to 1.6 will play a role in case of interface overriding.

Comment: I'm wondering about the class visibility. Are the classes in the same package ?