# Working on Android development in eclipse, I'm getting a "must override or implement a supertype method" error, researched solutions not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've tried every single of the preexisting solutions on this page (and multiple others), but none have not solved the problem: ['Must Override a Superclass Method' Errors after importing a project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips)

I went as far as to completely uninstall eclipse and java sdk/jre and then reinstall the android development tools suite directly from google and reinstall jdk 8.

I'm running windows 8.1 64bit, eclipse (kepler) is fully functional outside of this error. Let me know if there's any other information I can give that would be useful to know. I spent the entire day fighting with this, the fact that everyone else with the problem seems to have had such easy fixes makes me believe I'm either missing something stupid simple or my problem is very complex. Is there anything obvious I'd be likely to miss?

Any insights you could give me would be truly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you paste the part of code that is causing you problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have an @Override annotation on a function that isn't overriding a base function.  WHich is either a mistaken tag, a typo, or missing/changed parameters in the function signature.

Comment: @Antrromet The error is occuring in a completely unedited new Android project, so the mistake cannot be in the code.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by wiping my hard drive, installing Ubuntu and running eclipse :)

Answer (score 0):

```
then reinstall the android development tools suite directly from google and reinstall jdk 8
```

Android does not seems to have official support for JDK 8 now. [Please see this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

You have to try using the older version of java with android. Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Compiler` to update settings.

For understanding why JDK 8 is not yet supported by Android please read [this useful article](http://adilmughal.com/blog/2014/05/java-in-android-is-a-variant-of-java/) from one of my friend.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to install JDK 6? Because I've tried changing the compiler to 1.6 many times to no avail. I read the article and it doesn't seem to specify whether JDK must be set to 6 in eclipse or JDK 6 must be installed.

Comment: @Vito Yes please install JDK 6 to work with android. Give it a try that's the only problem I see here. Also refer to the 'System Requirements' section on android development page where they recommend to use jdk 6. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html