# Confusion with @Override annotation

Tags: apache-storm

I am new to Apache Storm 0.9.5.I am using eclipse with maven. Java version-1.7.

**Attempt 1:**
I am trying to do a sample code and followed the instructions given in the [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_working_example.htm)

```
import java.util.*;
//import storm tuple packages
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;

//import Spout interface packages
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;

//Create a class FakeLogReaderSpout which implement IRichSpout interface 
   to access functionalities

public class FakeCallLogReaderSpout implements IRichSpout {
   //Create instance for SpoutOutputCollector which passes tuples to bolt.
   private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
   private boolean completed = false;

   //Create instance for TopologyContext which contains topology data.
   private TopologyContext context;

   //Create instance for Random class.
   private Random randomGenerator = new Random();
   private Integer idx = 0;

   @Override
   public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
      this.context = context;
      this.collector = collector;
   }

   @Override
   public void nextTuple() {
      if(this.idx <= 1000) {
         List<String> mobileNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123401");
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123402");
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123403");
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123404");

         Integer localIdx = 0;
         while(localIdx++ < 100 && this.idx++ < 1000) {
            String fromMobileNumber = mobileNumbers.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(4));
            String toMobileNumber = mobileNumbers.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(4));

            while(fromMobileNumber == toMobileNumber) {
               toMobileNumber = mobileNumbers.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(4));
            }

            Integer duration = randomGenerator.nextInt(60);
            this.collector.emit(new Values(fromMobileNumber, toMobileNumber, duration));
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("from", "to", "duration"));
   }

   //Override all the interface methods
   @Override
   public void close() {}

   public boolean isDistributed() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void activate() {}

   @Override 
   public void deactivate() {}

   @Override
   public void ack(Object msgId) {}

   @Override
   public void fail(Object msgId) {}

   @Override
   public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
   }
}
```

The error message I receive is as follows

> The method cleanup() of type CallLogCreatorBolt must override a
>   superclass method

And the quick fix is to

> remove @Override annotation

When I removed the annotation I don’t see any error.

As we know, `IRichBolt` API has a method by the name `cleanup()` with same parameters. The idea of my class `CallLogCreatorBolt` is to override `cleanup()` present in `IRichBolt` class.

***1. My question is what is the problem in my using `@Override`?***

**Attempt 2:** 
I deleted all the methods inside the class `CallLogCreatorBolt`. Then I clicked on `Add unimplemented methods` option that eclipse provides.

```
public class CallLogCreatorBolt implements IRichBolt {

    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you notice, I have added `@Override` for `cleanup()` method alone. I get the same error as I receive in my first attempt. But other methods are fine.

Please forgive me if I am missing out something very basic! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like ur problem solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips).

Comment: @f1sherox : Thanks a lot. worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks to @f1sherox*

The issue was with JRE version. 
The project was executed in JRE1.5. But ideally, it should have been at least 1.6.

**The fix is as follows:**

Right click on your Project seen inside the Project Explorer/Navigator panel --> select properties --> Java Build Path --> Select on JRE system Library[JAVASE-1.5] --> Click on edit button --> Select appropriate JRE version you want[I chose version-1.7] --> Finish --> apply and Ok.

We are done :)